# Suggestion about server side android application

Tags: android

I'm working atm on an android application.

The app should be synchronized all the time with a server to get valid data.

My question is: Based on your experience, what kind of server side app should I use / develop?
The server should update all the connected clients once a change has been made. whats the best way to do that? also, how do I connect to that server from my App? (I guess such info will be easy to find once I choose the method)

Things that came to mind: java server side, apache, mysql etc.

Is something like that already exist so I can use or I should develop one for my own needs? Would love to get some suggestions.. kinda newb to android.

Comment: Take a look at Google Cloud Messaging.
It supports push messaging (instead of pull in most setups), this allows you to update all the connected clients. http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty broad. It really doesn't matter what technology you use on the server side as long as you write reliable and efficient API's that help keep the client and server data in sync. Use any server-side stack you like and think you can do well with.

If you don't want to write your own backend service and API's, you can use a BAAS (Backend As A Service) like [Parse](https://parse.com/). I've used them before and it's a great service.

Comment: Thanks, Is it possible , Using parse, to send information from the server to all connected clients fast?

Comment: Yes, you can use push notifications to do this easily.